# Get current Google user email and logout from Google

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an Web application that uses Google Drive. In order to make it easier for user to integrate his account (in this web application will be easier for client this way), I would like to have two links for authentication:

A link with the current user email that sends the user to the authorization page.
A link that automatically logout the current user from Google (if any) and send the user to authorization page (in this case the login page).

In order to accomplish that I need:
- the current Google user email
- logout current Google user

I really think this is not possible, but is it possible to me do this actions before have my application authorized by user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to pull a user's email address after they have authorized you to do so, so that isn't possible.

You can use OpenID to retrieve a user's email address or redirect them to the Google login page if they aren't logged in. They have to authorize your application, though, so you won't be able to direct them to different places until after they've signed in. There are details on the login flow at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Interaction.